# Remove the message in install4j

Tags: install4j

Delete the message that appears on the screen when the program runs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGKF2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown for installers built with the evaluation version. After you enter a purchased license key under "Help->Enter License Key" and rebuild the installer, it is not shown anymore.